# fix row bootstrap css

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

im working on HTML template using Bootstrap Css 
i want it to look like **Pinterest** (dynamic layout)
as you can see in the screen shot below it's not working like pinterest

[image: screen shot]

here is the code i use HTML

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span2">
TITLE Goes Here
Image
any content goes here
 </div>
<div class="span2">
TITLE Goes Here
Image
any content goes here
 </div>
<div class="span2">
TITLE Goes Here
Image
any content goes here
 </div>
<div class="span2">
TITLE Goes Here
Image
any content goes here
 </div>
<div class="span2">
TITLE Goes Here
Image
any content goes here
 </div>

</div>///End or Row div
```

i have try this code 
http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout

BUT it's not working on Firefox and it's not fit my code

so don't post it for me as a solution

Thanks in Command!

Comment: You're trying to put all of them in the same row... Try taking out the row div? Tell me what happens.

Comment: Have you tried writing any of your own CSS to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `column-fill` CSS line and it'll work in both webkit and fireFox.

```
#columns {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
  /*-webkit-column-fill: auto; REMOVE */
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-gap: 10px;
  /*-moz-column-fill: auto; REMOVE */
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 15px;
  column-fill: auto;
}
```

When you say "It's not fit my code", I don't get what you mean because it almost fits your code exactly:

They have:

```
<div id="columns">
  <div class="pin">
    stuff in here
  </div>
</div>
```

You have:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span2">
    stuff in here
  </div>
</div>
```

http://cssdeck.com/labs/qwexko5i

NOTE:  There are other ways to achieve this without using CSS3 columns and just using `display: inline-block` but you need to attempt some code yourself first.